# SwiftUI view over all the views including sheet view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I need to show a view above all views based upon certain conditions, no matter what the top view is. I am trying the following code:

```
    struct TestView<Presenting>: View where Presenting: View {
    
        /// The binding that decides the appropriate drawing in the body.
        @Binding var isShowing: Bool
        /// The view that will be "presenting" this notification
        let presenting: () -> Presenting
    
        var body: some View {
    
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    self.presenting()
    
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("Test")
                    }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 44,
                           height: 58)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.7))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .transition(.slide)
                    .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }

extension View {
    func showTopView(isShowing: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        TestView(isShowing: isShowing,
                               presenting: { self })
    }    
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @State var showTopView = false
   NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                content
            }
        }
        .showTopView(isShowing: $showTopView)

}
```

Now this is working fine in case of the views being pushed. But I am not able to show this TopView above the presented view.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63259094/12299030?

Comment: No, it does not @Asperi. I need a view to be shown on top, without considering what the current top view is, is the top view presented or pushed etc. It's like showing a loader on top of all views.

Answer (score -2):

I was recently dealing with a similar issue, but with Toast. I simply needed to display a Toast above both .sheet and .fullscreenCover. I found one solution that was quite capable, but due to certain limitations, I couldn't use it. I needed it to be in pure SwiftUI. In the end, I managed to solve it. It's not pure SwiftUI, but better than resorting to a UIKit wrapper and similar things. Here is the link to the my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/petomuro/ToastDemo) if it helps someone.

The main and essential aspects that you need to know take place in here:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ToastView: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    @State private var hostingController: UIHostingController<Toast>? = nil

    let message: String?

    func showToast(message: String) {
        let swiftUIView = Toast(message: message)
        hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
        hostingController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        hostingController?.view.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height,
            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
            height: 0)

        if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
           let window = windowScene.windows.first {
            window.addSubview(hostingController!.view)

            hostingController?.view.center.x = window.center.x

            let contentSize = hostingController!.view.sizeThatFits(CGSize(
                width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                hostingController?.view.frame.origin.y = window.frame.height - contentSize.height
                hostingController?.view.frame.size.height = contentSize.height
            }
        }
    }

    func dismissToast() {
        hostingController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        hostingController = nil
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            content

            if isPresented, let message = message {
                VStack {}
                    .onAppear {
                        showToast(message: message)
                    }
                    .onChange(of: message) { newValue in
                        dismissToast()
                        showToast(message: newValue)
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        dismissToast()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Here is a way for your goal, you do not need Binding, just use let value.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isShowing: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomView(isShowing: isShowing, content: { yourContent }, isShowingContent: { isShowingContent })
        
    }
    
    var yourContent: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
                
                Text("Hello, World!")
                
                Button("Show isShowing Content") { isShowing = true }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("My App")
            
        }
        
    }
    
    var isShowingContent: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.black.opacity(0.5).ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("Close isShowing Content") { isShowing = false }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.blue.cornerRadius(10.0))
                    .padding()
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct CustomView<Content: View, IsShowingContent: View>: View {
    
    let isShowing: Bool
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    @ViewBuilder let isShowingContent: () -> IsShowingContent
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Group {
            
            if isShowing { ZStack { content().blur(radius: isShowing ? 5.0 : 0.0); isShowingContent() } }
            else { content() }
 
        }
        .animation(.default, value: isShowing)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working in case of the presented view. Nothing is shown above the presented view.

Comment: Yes, I tried your code. Please try to present something with sheet and you will see that custom view is never shown above sheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277120/overlay-swiftui-view-over-all-other-views-including-sheets
This is the question I want answer for actually

Comment: With my answer you do not need to use sheet! My code is sheet!

Comment: @ioscoder is it possible that the view is on top of elements in the navigationbar too? When I tried only the Title was covered but not the rest of the bar.