# SwiftUI View on top of NavigationTitle and toolbar with "hole" in it

Tags: ios, swiftui

is it possible to have a view on top of everything (including the NavigationTitle and toolbar)? And is it possible to create a "hole" in this view?

I would like to code some kind of tutorial as show in the picture below. I tried the following, but the navigationtitle and the toolbar isn't covered.

[SwiftUI view over all the views including sheet view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032774/swiftui-view-over-all-the-views-including-sheet-view)

edit: The part with the hole was solved in this question: [SwiftUI: Adapt size and position of one View to another View](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74275416/19561788)

[image: screenshot of wanted result]
[image: screenshot of what I was able to do]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to place the see-through view on top of the whole NavigationView using a ZStack, not only the child-view I wanted to be in the background. Than the Navigationtitle and everything in the toolbar is also darkened.

embarassingly simple...