# Display View on top off bottom sheet

Tags: swiftui, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to implement a view that displays error message for my whole app.
I want this view to always be above every other view, but I also use sheets in my app and in that case the error message is hidden behind the sheet, since the sheet is displayed above every other view.

[image]
[image]

Here is a View to reproduce my situation:

```
struct AppView: View {
    @State var isPresentingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button("Toggle sheet") {
                    isPresentingSheet.toggle()
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSheet) {
                Text("Im above everything else")
            }
             
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "xclose")
                    Text("I want to be even above the sheet")
                }
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(Padding.l)
                .background(Color.red.opacity(0.2))
                .overlay(
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red),
                    alignment: .bottom
                )
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if it's possible to display a view above a sheet, but to me it looks like the sheet is in a completely different window?
But maybe it's possible to create a custom sheet that moves in from the top and is displayed above other *native* sheets?

Comment: instead of using a sheet you can create a custom view and give some animation.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77533196/11217849

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested, I have created a custom bottom sheet with simple controls and snap functionality.
The bottom sheet has a `zIndex` of `1` so you can easily place views above it with a greater `zIndex`.
You can find it here: [AlternativeSheet](https://github.com/JonasHiltl/AlternativeSheet).

[image]

Here is the code to achieve the view of the image above.

```
import AlternativeSheet
...
ZStack {
    VStack {
        Button("Toggle sheet") {
            isPresentingSheet.toggle()
        }
    }
    .alternativeSheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSheet, snaps: [0.95]) {
        Text("Im above everything else")
    }
    .isDraggable()
    .dampenDrag()
     
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "xclose")
            Text("I want to be even above the sheet")
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(Padding.l)
        .background(Color.red.opacity(0.3))
        .overlay(
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 1)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red),
            alignment: .bottom
        )
        Spacer()
    }
}
```